# How to style an date input's calendar icon in Firefox > 108?

Tags: css, firefox, datepicker

In older versions of Firefox (until 109), it was possible to select the date picker's icon like in Chromium:

```css
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none; /* Hides the icon in Chrome and Firefox < v109 */
}
```

It's no longer possible that way, see also [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/kslstn/pen/rNZRNyx?editors=1100). Does anyone know a workaround?

My date inputs have custom icons and now show two of them in the newish Firefox versions. For now, I'm doing some user agent sniffing and add a CSS class so I can remove my custom icon:

```js
    const userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    const regex = /Firefox\/(?<majorRelease>\d+(\.\d+)?)/
    const match = userAgent.match(regex)
    const FirefoxVersion = match ? Number(match.groups.majorRelease) : null
    if (FirefoxVersion > 108){
        const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input[type="date"]')
        inputs.forEach((el)=>{
            el.classList.add('input-date-firefox-fix')
        })
    }
```

Comment: Is this [reported bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1811554) relevant to your issue?

Comment: I don't think so, but there's [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1812397) that was opened after the 109 release.

Comment: I suggest you brute force your custom icon onto the screen by positioning it over the current icon and use the CSS style `pointer-events: none;`.

Comment: Yeah, that requires that the custom icon has a background color covering the default icon. Because my input field changes color upon focus, this is messy to implement. Although, maybe I can add a pseudo element to cover the original icon with the input's background color. That should be quite easy to keep in sync.

Comment: Oh no, the [pseudo element is not an option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660434/1171638).

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I'm in the same situation as you...

Answer (score -1):

I ended up finding in the Firefox options to access the shadow DOM:

Access options in the navigation bar:

```
about:config
```

After that:

```
devtools.inspector.showAllAnonymousContent true
```

Then restart the browser.

We therefore find a:

```
button#calendar-button
```

But since it is in the shadow DOM I don't yet know how to target it...